# How to access response header using JSP EL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

`${response}` is null

`${pageContext.response}` seems to belong to sitemesh filter.

I am trying to conditionally add the "manifest" attribute to the html tag depending on whether a response cache header is present or not.

UPDATE:

Brain-fart on my part. I was trying `${pageContext.response.header['Cache-Control']}` while the correct way is `${pageContext.response.getHeader('Cache-Control')}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very straightforward example on accessing response headers: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/getHeader.html

So I think these should both work:

```
<%
    pageContext.setAttribute("cacheHeader", response.getHeader("cacheHeaderIamLookingFor"));
%>

<c:if test="${!empty cacheHeader}">
    ... add your manifest stuff ..
</c:if>
```

I believe this should also work:

```
<c:if test="${!empty pageContext.response.getHeader('cacheHeaderIamLookingFor')}">
    ... add your manifest stuff ..
</c:if>
```